# netlogo: Do you know how to take the X axis information where there is a turtle with the biggest ID?

Tags: count, netlogo

I would like to take the X axis information where there is a turtle with the biggest ID with some specific conditions. And I want to count the number of turtles on the right side of the X axis information. The following is a sample program. I would like to draw a code to obtain X axis information where there is a turtle with the largest ID at the point "here?" in this sample program. Thank you for your advice.
(this link is the 3D image https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQf93.png)

```
count turtles with [xcor >  "here?"  ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lot of ambiguity in your question, but you should be able to change the following to meet your needs.

```
turtles-own [ID] ;if unique, you can just use `who`

to setup  ;make some turtles with various xcors and IDs
  ca
  crt 100 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set ID random 1000
  ]
end

to-report top ;get a turtle with biggest id
  report max-one-of turtles [ID]
end

to-report winners ;get turtles to right of top
  let topx [xcor] of top
  report turtles with [xcor > topx]
end

to test
  setup
  print count winners
end
```

Comment: @goodgest It sounds like you need to ask a separate question.  But before you do so, please ponder this rule of thumb: reporters are your friend.  (I.e., do not assume you cannot easily use these reporters or variants thereof. Nothing stops your form calling a reporter inside your `to-end` procedure.)